# how to sum two numbers from input tag?

Tags: javascript, input, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add two strings as if they were numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976627/how-to-add-two-strings-as-if-they-were-numbers)

I wrote a simple JavaScript code and I want to use two input box and add numbers from the two value. Here's the code, and I see the result 1520 instead of 35.

How can I fix it?

```
n1 <input type = "number" id = "n1" value=15 />
n2 <input type = "number" id = "n2" value=20 />

<p>Sum?</p>
<button onclick="sum()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo2">Result?? </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function sum() 
{ 
    var fn, ln; 
    fn = document.getElementById("n1").value; 
    ln = document.getElementById("n2").value; 
    result =  (fn+ln); 
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `parseInt()`, or `parseFloat()`; the problem you were experiencing is that you were concatenating two strings, not adding two numbers. `parseInt()` (assuming that it finds a real number) addresses that issue by converting the string to a number:

```
 function sum() 
{ 
    var fn, ln, result; 
    fn = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value, 10);
    ln = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value, 10);
    result =  (fn+ln); 
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result; 
}
```

The `, 10` that appears after the `value` is the radix, which ensures which number-base the returned number (if any) will be.

Also note that the `result` variable should be declared within the function as well, to avoid polluting the global scope (and possibly creating problems with other variables elsewhere).

References:

- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Shouldn't `result` be declared as a local variable?  Or, just get rid of it entirely and use `document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = (fn + ln);`.

Comment: Well, yes: I was being a little bit lazy. (*corrected*) =)

Answer (score 4):

```
result =  (parseFloat(fn)+parseFloat(ln));
```