# How to calculate sum using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two inputs from textboxes.and i want to display sum of those two values in another textbox.this is how i did it.but when i entered 2and 3 it display 23 in 3rd text box.i want to display 5 on 3rd text box.what is the wrong and how can solve it?

```
    var sale=document.getElementById("sale").value;  // enter 2

    var sale2=document.getElementById("sale2").value; // enter 3


    document.getElementById('calsale').value = ((sale2)+(sale)); //now display23.want  to display 5
```

Comment: ... see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961474/how-to-sum-two-numbers-from-input-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `parseInt` function. In facts, values get tanks to `getElementById("sale").value` are string and not numbers. You have to cast them into real integers to make the sum (otherwise it will make the concatenation of the two strings)

```
var sale=parseInt(document.getElementById("sale").value);  // enter 2
var sale2=parseInt(document.getElementById("sale2").value); // enter 3

document.getElementById('calsale').value = ((sale2)+(sale));
```