# javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple program that make the sum of two numbers BUT.. 
the program is concatenating instead, This is so confusing!
Can anyone help?

```js
function calculate() {
  var numberOne = document.querySelector(".first").value;
  var numberTwo = document.querySelector(".second").value;
  var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;
  document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "The sum of the two numbers is : " + sum;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>Calculate sum of two numbers !</p>
  Enter 1rst Number:<br>
  <input type="number" class="first" placeholder=""><br><br> Enter 2nd Number:<br>
  <input type="number" class="second" placeholder=""><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="calculate">
  <p class="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: look at this answer +num1 + +num2; -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8976659/5323912

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here `value` gives you a string, hence the concatenation. Try parsing it as an Number instead:

```
var sum = parseInt(numberOne) + parseInt(numberTwo);
```

See the [demo **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yb8r1wnw/2/).

Answer (score 3):

Javascript takes dom elements as string only by default. To make mathematical calculation, you need to typecast it to integer/float or convert to number.

```
parseInt(number) = number, truncates after decimal value
parseFloat(number) = number with decimal values
Number(number) = number with or without decimal
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `numberOne` and `numberTwo` are strings, so you get concatenated strings when use `+` sign with two string. 
Parse first to numbers then sum them. You can use [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [**parseFloat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) functions for it.

```js
var numberOne = '7';
var numberTwo = '8';

var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;
console.log(sum);

sum = parseFloat(numberOne) + parseFloat(numberTwo);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt()` for this, Check snippet below

```js
function calculate() {
    var numberOne = document.querySelector(".first").value;
    var numberTwo = document.querySelector(".second").value;
    var sum = parseInt(numberOne) + parseInt(numberTwo);
    document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "The sum of the two numbers is : " + sum;
  }
```

```html
 <p>Calculate sum of two numbers !</p>
  Enter 1rst Number:<br>
  <input type="number" class="first" placeholder=""><br><br>
  Enter 2nd Number:<br>
  <input type="number" class="second" placeholder=""><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="calculate">
  <p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example , you can use this:

```
var numberOne:number = +document.querySelector(".first").value;
var numberTwo:number = +document.querySelector(".second").value;
var sum = numberOne + numberTwo;
```

You should use `+` Angular typeScript

Comment: Worked for me. parseInt did not. But then I was fixing a concatenation issue regarding my image slide indexes in an image modal/slider.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because value returns with string. So sum operation ends with concatenation.
you need to convert both those values.

user below code

```
 var sum = parseFloat(numberOne) + parseFloat(numberTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Who are using javascript in salesforce make sure

```
var a= 8 ;
var b =8 ;
var c = a+b;
```

This will give u result output = 88;
It is will just concatenate. If you want to add those two:
You should write logic as :

```
var a = 8;
var b = 8
var c = parseInt(a)+ parseInt(b);
```

This will give you the desired result of 16 , The same is the case with multiplication.

Hope this helps.