# Sum up all 'score' values from object arrays inside React props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Sorry for the tongue twister of a title but its a very specific problem.

Currently I have a array of objects being past through by props. I'm trying to sum up all the 'score' values together and display it in my app.

The object looks like this:

```
[{'id': '1', 'score': '10'}, {'id': '2', 'score': '20'}, {'id': '3', 'score': '35'}]
```

And inside the app it is being called as followed:

```
state = { 
     content: this.props.navigation.getParam('content', false),
}
```

---

```
scoreCount = () => {
    const content = this.state.content;

    if (content) {
        return content.reduce((prev, current) => prev.score + current.score);
    } else {
        return false;
}
```

---

```
render() {

const score = this.scoreCount()

return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Score:</Text>
                    { score ?
                        <Text>
                            { score }
                        </Text> :
                        <Text>
                            0
                        </Text>
                    }
                </View>
)}
```

It shows 'undefined35' on return

I know it has something to do with the props not being available on time of the call, but im not sure how to return it the score properly to the View

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What error is it giving? Those are strings btw, not numbers, so I don't think it will give the result you are expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840501/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum) and [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you are trying to add the string because the value of `score` is `'10'` and so on which are string . So you can use unary operator to convert it to number. Secondly I think `prev.score` will be an issue during the first addition since there is no `score` key. So in the reduce a `0` being passed which will be considered as first element

```js
let content = [{
  'id': '1',
  'score': '10'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'score': '20'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'score': '35'
}];

let sum = content.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return prev + +current.score
}, 0);
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: The Unary Operator did it :)

Thank you