# 59-60 second Coordinate issue

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems

everyone, who read this.

I found an issue that latitude or longitude of geocoordinate with, for example, 2 minutes and 59 seconds, after converting to decimal format, has value "0.049722", but

- 2 minutes and 60 seconds has value "0.35", but I thought it must be equal to equal to
- 3 minutes and 00 seconds, that has value "0.05"
- 3 minutes and 00 seconds, that has value "0.05"

But again
2 minutes and 61 seconds, that has expected value "0.050278"

Is it global geocoordinate issue or online converter issue?

I use http://the-mostly.ru/konverter_geograficheskikh_koordinat.html

Comment: `2/60.+60/3600. == 3/60. == 0.05`

Comment: Thank you, @kvantour. So 2 minutes and 60 seconds that has value "0.35" is just error of implementation of online converter ?

Comment: 0.35 degrees is for sure wrong! If you use the inverse conversion, you notice it converts it to 21 minutes. So yes, the site is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the source of the respective website, you notice the following line:

```
if (LAsec==60) {LAsec = 0;LAminutes = LAminutes+1;}
```

Since `LAminutes` is still a string, this represents a string concatenation, so `2` is converted to `21` instead of `3`.

See: [javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840501/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum)

In short, the website is very wrong!

Maybe you should use WolframAlpha for this:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0+deg+2%27+60%22+N,+0+deg+E