# shopping cart project using pure java script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this code to calculate the total  for my shopping cart project, but it just concatenates the two prices together

I tried making separate variables but it didn't work.

```
document.querySelector('.totalBtn').addEventListener('click', fillTotal);

function fillTotal(){

      let a = document.querySelector('.landingHempOil').innerHTML;
      let b = document.querySelector('.fishOilLanding').innerHTML;
       document.querySelector('.totalLanding').innerHTML= a + b; 
}
```

What happens is the total shows the two concatenated next to each other rather than adding the two prices together. how could I do this better?

Comment: `innerHtml` is a string.  `+` for strings concatenates them.  So turn them into numbers first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961000/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum-of-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840501/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum

Comment: is there a reason you are using innerHTML? innerText ? nodeValue?

Comment: @Estradiaz Probably just following a tutorial, or it was the first thing they found online that worked.  I doubt they weighed the various options and chose the optimal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse `a` and `b` to numeric values like following:

```
document.querySelector('.totalLanding').innerHTML= parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  it works with the parseFloat() built in function

Answer (score 0):

Convert the innerhtml value to integer to do the Math.

```
let a = document.querySelector('.landingHempOil').innerHTML;
let b = document.querySelector('.fishOilLanding').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.totalLanding').innerHTML= parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
```

Comment: thank you, what are they considered if they are not numbers just out of curiosity?

Comment: innerHTML returns them as string value eg: "2"+"3"="23". So the result become "23" instead of 5

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the values are not numbers. You need to convert them into numbers before adding them. You could use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)(), or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)().

```
function fillTotal(){

      let a = document.querySelector('.landingHempOil').innerHTML;
      let b = document.querySelector('.fishOilLanding').innerHTML;
       document.querySelector('.totalLanding').innerHTML= Number(a) + Number(b); 
}
```