# Angular Calculate Sum of Input Field

Tags: arrays, angular

I am building array of values which will be typed into input field. Array looks like this example:

```
[{mykey:"32"},{mykey:"32"}]
```

I tried to calculate sum of it with this example:

```
reduce(function(prev2, cur) {
      return prev2 + cur.mykey;
    }, 0);
```

But it only put numbers behind. And don`t calculate. Maybe my array should look like this to calculate? How to get right input as number instead of string?

```
[{mykey:32},{mykey:32}]
```

Comment: you need to do prev2.myKey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript (+) sign concatenates instead of giving sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840501/javascript-sign-concatenates-instead-of-giving-sum)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert string to a number before adding. [Number - MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
reduce(function(prev2, cur) {
    return prev2 + Number(cur.mykey);
}, 0);
```