# Why I can not use + in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Function</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sum(x,y) {
            var z = x+y;
            document.write("Sum is"+z);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="" id="t1" name=""/>
        <input type="" id="t2" name=""/>
        <input type="button" onclick="sum(t1.value,t2.value)" value="Click me"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi Guys, I am a beginner with JavaScript and I'm facing this little problem. If I enter 5 and 5 the result is 55. But I want to sum up these values.

Comment: `t1.value` and `t2.value` are strings. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976627/how-to-add-two-strings-as-if-they-were-numbers

Comment: Turn the strings into integers.

Comment: [Number Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: use parseInt() if it is interge

Comment: To be on the safe side change to `var z = parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y)`

Answer (score 0):

As @TonyDong said, uses parseInt to convert the string to int if desired input is integer.

To make your function works better, you need to validate the inputs first before sum.

**Below is one example:**

1. make the type of two inputs are 'number'
2. `checkValidity()` for the form or two inputs in function=sum. if validated, sum the values, if not, return error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Function</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sum(x,y)
        {
            if(document.getElementById("submit").checkValidity()) {
              var z = parseInt(x)+parseInt(y);
              document.write("Sum is "+z);
            }
            else {
              document.write("Input value must be Int!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="submit">
        <input id="t1" name="" type="number"/>
        <input id="t2" name="" type="number"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="sum(t1.value,t2.value)" value="Click me"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know why down vote? If anything is wrong, let me know. I will update or delete the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should covert x and y to integers first, like parseInt(x) and parseInt(y) while doing the summation.
Then, instead of document.write, you can use console.log.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Function</title>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
function sum(x,y) { 
var z = parseInt(x)+parseInt(y); 
console.log("Sum is",z); 
} 
</script>
 </head>
 <body> 
<form>
 <input type="" id="t1" name=""/>
 <input type="" id="t2" name=""/> 
<input type="button" onclick="sum(t1.value,t2.value)" value="Click me"/> 
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```