# How to use numbers taken from prompt() and use in calculation?

Tags: javascript

I am using the prompt() function and asking for users to enter 2 numbers which I then want to calculate the sum and return the answer on an alert.

```
var numOne = prompt('Give me a number'); 
var numTwo = prompt('Give me another number'); 
alert('The sum of your numbers is ' + numOne+numTwo);
```

It seems that javascript is using the numbers as strings and just returning a result with the 2 numbers side by side in a string??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add two strings as if they were numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976627/how-to-add-two-strings-as-if-they-were-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prompt()` method only returns a string.

You have to convert the string to a number using these methods:

- `Number()`
- `parseInt()`
- `parseFloat()`

Generally you can use `Number()` method.

Add a `sum` variable and store the sum result of the numbers to it. The code is given below:

```
var numOne = prompt('Give me a number'); 
var numTwo = prompt('Give me another number'); 
var sum = Number(numOne) + Number(numTwo);
alert('The sum of your numbers is ' + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert('The sum of your numbers is ' + (parseInt(numOne)+ parseInt(numTwo));
```

or

```
var numOne = parseInt(prompt('Give me a number')); 
var numTwo = parseInt(prompt('Give me another number')); 
alert('The sum of your numbers is ' + numOne+numTwo);
```